# Python UDP socket receive - server.recvfrom package size longer than bufsize

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm using the socket module for a UDP server。The incoming packets always have a different size(0-65535), so client send package length first, then send the package；server receives data according to the package length and 1024 per server receives。but server didn't work like I thought，it can receives package only once。

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import socket

ip_port = ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server.bind(ip_port)
print('server listen......')


def recv_header(s_socket):
    try:
        msg, addr = s_socket.recvfrom(32)
        return json.loads(msg), addr
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e), None


while True:
    header_msg, client_addr = recv_header(s_socket=server)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    receiverBufsize = 1024
    if client_addr is None:
        print (header_msg)
        continue
    data_body = ""
    package_len = int(header_msg['length'])
    print ("package_len: {}".format(package_len))
    print ("client_addr: {}".format(str(client_addr)))
    while package_len > 0:
        if package_len > receiverBufsize:
            body_part = server.recvfrom(receiverBufsize)
        else:
            body_part = server.recvfrom(package_len)
        data_body += body_part[0]
        package_len -= receiverBufsize
    print ("data_body: {}".format(data_body))
```

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import socket
import random

ip_port = ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)


def get_data(length):
    base_str = 'ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    return ''.join([random.choice(base_str) for _ in range(length)])


while 1:
    msg = raw_input('>>>：')
    if msg == 'q':
        break
    if not msg:
        continue
    len = int(msg)
    client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    data = get_data(len)
    header = json.dumps({"length": len})
    aa = client.sendto(header.encode('utf-8'), ip_port)
    print aa
    aa = client.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), ip_port)
    print aa
```

If the packet length is less than 1024(my receiverBufsize), it works normally
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNTqo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd6D5.png)

If the packet length is more than 1024(my receiverBufsize), socket.recvfrom will block
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USzxN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMkit.png)

Comment: In real-world networking the practical limit for UDP packets is 1280 bytes (including all headers!).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @VPfB You're making some assumptions there, including a) no jumbo frames b) no IP fragmentation. 65,535 isn't possible in IPv4 but 65,507 is possible. I wouldn't recommend it, but you can do it

Comment: Fragmentation is a bad thing in IPv4 and there is no fragmentation in IPv6. Jumbo frames are ethernet frames. I say it again - 1280 is a practical limit. Surely you can send larger packets if some conditions are met, but that increases the probability the connection will not work reliably over Internet.

Answer (score 1):

UDP is a message oriented protocol, not a data stream like TCP. This means in UDP a single `send` is matched by a single `recv`.

This means you cannot use multiple `recv` with a small buffer (size 1024 in your case) to get data which were sent in a single `send` with a larger buffer - you need to use `recv` with a large enough buffer instead.

This means also that you don't actually need to send the length upfront, since you don't need to add message semantics to a protocol which already has message semantic. In contrary, sending the length in a separate message as you do could actually be harmful since UDP is an unreliable protocol and you cannot rely on packets getting delivered in order, at all or only once.

Comment: thanks, small buffer is really unnecessary